# wp_enqueue_script only on certain page templates

Tags: wordpress

I am doing this in a plugin. I have the following in an attempt to only enqueue a script when my template file `archive-my_custom_post_type.php` is used.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue');

function my_enqueue($hook) {
if(is_page_template('archive-my_custom_post_type')){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-scripts', plugins_url( '/js/myjquery.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
}
```

}

It is not working.  It does not load the jquery file on ANY front-end pages, let alone when `archive-my_custom_post_type.php` is rendered. However, when I remove that `if` conditional, it loads on ALL my front-end pages.

**Question**: How can I do a conditional enqueue of a script whenever my custom post type archive template is being used?

Comment: Your call is incorrect. Look at the examples of the [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/#comment-497) in the [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/)

Comment: Have you tried `is_tax()`? See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the complete file name, including `.php`. So in your case you will need to use:

```
is_page_template('archive-my_custom_post_type.php')
```

Also, if your template is under a subdirectory you will need to specify that as well.
Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/#more-information

Comment: hmm, still not working for me unfortunately.  I even put in `wp_reset_query()` just in case (from docs in your link), but that didn't do the trick either.

Comment: I have the plugin "Show Current Template" installed, and that is showing the exact template I am trying to check for.  So: the "Show Current Template" is able to get the template name ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using is_page_template function, you should also use as parameter the full path (including subdirectories) for the template. For example, if your template is located in your-theme-directory/templates/template-file.php then you should use it like this:

```
if(is_page_template('templates/template-file.php')){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-scripts', plugins_url( '/js/myjquery.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
}
```